# Error using orditorp: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R, and I'm trying to display species names in a CCA plot. I found that you can use orditorp after creating a blank CCA plot to replace the default points with truncated species names. However, when I try to run the orditorp function I get the error message:

```
Error in x[ord, ] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In x[, 1] - w :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x[, 1] + w :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x[, 2] - h :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In x[, 2] + h :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The code I'm running is below:

```
bmi_all<- read.delim("BMI_data_all_var.txt", header=T, sep="\t", row.names=1)
library(vegan)
taxa.matrix <- subset(bmi_all, select=Chironomidae:Neoporus)
attach(bmi_all)
#perform a correspondance analysis on my bmi data
bmi_ca<- cca(taxa.matrix~TSS+BChla+SChla+DSub, na.action=na.exclude)
cnam<-make.cepnames(names(taxa.matrix))
stems<-colSums(taxa.matrix)
plot(bmi_ca, dis="sp", type="n")
orditorp(bmi_ca,"sp",label=cnam,priority=stems,pch="+",pcol="red")
```

If I run `plot(bmi_ca, dis="sp", type="t")` I get a CCA plot but as expected the species names create a very cluttered ordination. I've tried replacing `taxa.matrix` with `bmi_ca` when creating both `cnam` and `stems`, but I get the same error when trying to apply `orditorp`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

-Jordan

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I managed to solve my problem! I had removed a site from my dataset and this resulted in some species having abundances of zero. After I removed them and ran the code, it worked!